# How do I setup a RapidSSL cert on modulus.io?

Tags: ssl, meteor, modulus.io

I'm trying to setup ssl on modulus.io but the guide says to bundle four files:
http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1701165-ssl-setup-guide

The problem is rapid ssl only gives me two and they aren't named anything like those.

They only give me a web certificate, intermediate CA and then link to some bundled CA.

Anyone else do this in the past that can link me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bundle all the provided certs in a specific order. The order depends on the SSL provider. The Modulus guide is showing Namecheap. The likely order based on the info you provided is:

1. Domain specific cert - usually has your domain name in the filename.
2. The intermediate CA.
3. The contents of the bundled CA.

Simply concatenate all of these into a single file and provide that to Modulus. You can then use [ssl-checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to verify the certificate chain is complete and in the right order.

Disclaimer: I'm a Modulus employee

Comment: Thanks I got it working by doing this and disabling meteors force ssl package (now using the one on your website)